# Swift - Add granularity in Array (2 by 2, 5 by 5, etc..)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, swift3

I'm currently working with the "Charts" pod.

My app shows a bar chart of athletes results, with:

> - X Axis: number of reps / time / rounds / weight
> - Y Axis: number of athletes

I would like to gather the number of reps in different groups.

Something that would be like: 10 < x < 20, 20 < x < 30, etc... Rather than the real total of reps / time / whatever.

Something like that: 
[image]

Depending on the difference between the `Max()` and `Min()` value, I want to change the granularity.

This is what I have right now:

```
let resultTime = [2458, 3500, 3600] // Fake data -> 41min, 58min, 60 min
let dict = Dictionary(grouping: resultTime, by: { $0 / 60 }).map { ($0.key, $0.value.count) }
```

This way, I can have a dictionary grouped by minute. I got this:

```
[(58, 1), (40, 1), (60, 1)]
```

I would like to group these data 2 by 2, to have something like that instead:

```
[(60, 2), (40, 1)]
```

Is there a possibly to play with the granularity with `groupBy`?

Comment: You just need to tweak your `by` function, to implement the rounding you desire. What does "2 by 2" mean?

Comment: Sorry I'm French, the translation must be bad... Something like [0, 2, 4, 6etc...] or with 5 [0, 5, 10, 15, etc..]

Comment: So change your `by` function to round to the nearest 2 or 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Alexander said, the solution is to round the `by` function

You can do that with this little function:

```
func roundWithCoef(_ x : Double, coef: Int) -> Int {
      return coef * Int(round(x / Double(coef)))
}

let dict = Dictionary(grouping: resultTime, by: { roundWithCoef(Double($0 / 60), coef: 4) }).map { ($0.key, $0.value.count) }
```

This way you can play with the coef number